# HOw can I logout from google from another component using ng-angular-social-login

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I am using [angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login).  I can sign in with Google in the loginComponent:

```
this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
  data => {
    this.socialUser = data;
  })
```

I have this structure:

```
app
 auth
  loginComponent
 shared
  menuComponent(here is the link logout)
```

When I try to logout from menuComponent appears an error: You are not logged In.

```
logout(): void {
      this.authSocialService.signOut()
        .then( res => console.log( res ) )
        .catch( err => console.log(err) )
}
```

My question is how can I logout from menuComponent of the session opened in the loginComponent?

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) is recreated the error in Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To issues a logout it's simple just call the signOut() from the service in any of your components, but make sure to import SocialAuthService first. Here's an example.

```
import { SocialAuthService, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
 user: SocialUser;

     constructor(private authService: SocialAuthService) {}

     ngOnInit() {
       this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log(user);
     });
   }

   signOut(): void {
    this.authService.signOut();
  }
    
    }
```

Comment: i had imported the socialAuthService: SocialAuthService in the constructor and I sign out of the session but in console print a error : not logged in

Comment: can you try to recreate the error in stackblitz or post some code :)

Comment: Hello.  Here is the link in Stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j3xunj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu%2Fmenu.component.ts.  I'm going to udpate the answer above.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fbxfsk?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.ts

Comment: Hello @Karimov.  Your answer in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fbxfsk?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.ts worked for me.  Thanks.

Comment: glad to help, if you would not mind upvote the stackblitz comment thanks.